# Cannot delete directory

Tags: filesystem, directory, delete

I have a folder which I cannot delete. I cannot even list its contents. This folder was being used to store some logs which increased significantly to be out of control because of some scripting error, and now its content is flooding my hard drive. When I try to run an `rm -r <folder_name>` it just stalls and nothing happens. Eventually I lost patience and I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Do you have any idea how to get rid of this folder?

Comment: Have you tried `rm -fr`? '-f' == force.

Comment: Find/kill/fix the "scripting error". Then delete the folder.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to run an rm -r  it just stalls and nothing happens.

Depending on what filesystem and hardware is in use, this may take *significant* time. Deleting a lot of small files may easily take a minute on a normal hard drive.

You can run `rm -rv /path` to show what `rm` is actually doing. You're likely to see that it's in fact busy removing things.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
sudo rm -rfv /path/to/directory_to_delete
```

This will run `rm` as `root`; delete recursively; ignore errors and permissions (even if files don't exist), and explain what is being done.